# Integral involving Gamma Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am solving the following integral:

$$
\int_{-1}^{K} u^B e^{-u} du
$$

The solution of the integral is a lower incomplete Gamma Function if -1 is replaced with 0. Can anybody help me in solving the integral so that the solution involves an incomplete gamma function (either upper or lower)?

Regards

Comment: I would break it up into two integrals. One from $-1$ to $0$ and one from $0$ to $K$, but I'm not sure if the low incomplete gamma function is defined for negative numbers

Comment: Of course, i can also break it up into 2 separate  integrals but i don't know about the integral solution from -1 to 0.

Comment: I guess the main thing is if you can integrate from $-1$ to $\infty$. It would be a "upper" incomplete gamma. Still unsure on how it is defined

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work.

$$I=\int_{-1}^K u^B e^{-u}du=\int_{-1}^{\infty}u^B e^{-u}du-\int_K^{\infty}u^B e^{-u}du   $$

Then,

$$\Gamma(z,x)=\int_x^{\infty}u^{z-1} e^{-u}du   $$

So our integrals are...

$$ I=\Gamma\left(B+1,-1\right)-\Gamma\left(B+1,K\right) $$

The incomplete gamma function for with a negative bound seems to behave ok.  I did a little research and found the "generalized incomplete gamma function."  Which is,

$$\Gamma(z,x_1,x_2) =\int_{x_1}^{x_2}u^{z-1} e^{-u}du $$

This is defined for complex $a$, $x_1$, and $x_2$.  Full details on branch cuts and such can be found here: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma3/04/05/03/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very helpful.

Comment: To do what? $ $

Comment: Nobody knows @Did